# are you able to type into a UILabel

Tags: iphone, text, keyboard, uilabel

Hi I am wondering if you are able to use the ios keyboard to update a textfield as the user types?

Answer (score 1):

you could get each character as they type through [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate) delegate methods,
Once you get the set of character through delegate method , you could update you `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about UITextField, then yes, naturally, those are meant to be modified by the user and interact with the keyboard just fine. If you're talking about UILabel, then no, the user can't type directly into a label, but as @Jhaliya suggests you could update the label whenever the user changes a text field, text view, or other object that can interact with the keyboard.